# Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'

Tags: java, android, gradle, ionic-framework

I have a issue with:
-ionic cordova build android,
I get:

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.952 secs
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\mpta\Desktop\projekt\AssemblyApp\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml:32:53-81: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'networkSecurityConfig' with value '@xml/network_security_config').

C:\Users\mpta\Desktop\projekt\AssemblyApp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\xml\config.xml:32: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'networkSecurityConfig' with value '@xml/network_security_config').

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

  ```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ```

I have tried many options,and any solutions doesn't work to me.

Comment: Check `root > resources > android > xml` folder in your project. if not then google how to add network security file in cordova project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.